# Deploy Django+React js

Tags: react, django

Olá, gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas. Suponha que eu queira fazer uma api para uma aplicação de loja utilizando Django e o frontend utilizando react js. Como funcionaria o deploy da aplicação, eu precisaria fazer o deploy dos dois projetos independentemente? Tem como pagar colocar tudo no mesmo lugar? Custaria mais caro fazer desta forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode contratar um serviço de cloud (aws,digital ocean,heroku) e por ai vai e criar uma instância ( como se fosse um computador virtual alocado na nuvem), e rodar sua aplicação similar a o modo que você roda na sua máquina local acessando via SSH , o CLI do serviço se disponível.

Em relação a custo,tudo depende do meio que você quer escalar sua aplicação e do tamanho dela, se for algo pequeno pode rodar tudo junto que não vai existir grander problemas.

Comment: se você puder em indicar algum tutorial eu agradesceria